# Implementing onClick on Fragment: Set the on click listener on Fragment or on Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am working with Android and it seems that there are two ways to implement the listener for the user click.

**Option 1:**
When the trigger is in XML of the fragment and it sets the attribute onClick.
For example, here is a piece of the View of Fragment

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/userClickButton"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="myOnClickListener"
    android:text="Click on Me"
/>
```

Set the method MyOnClickListener in the Activity

```
public void MyOnClickListener(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) { 
        case R.id.useerClickButton:
            break;
    }
}
```

Advantages:

- Unique OnClickListener for all the fragments
- All the variables could be centralized in the Activity

Disadvantages:

- When there is a lot of fragments related with the same activity, there could be several confusions.
- The listener of the click must be public

**Option 2**
When the xml there is not attribute of onClick but in Fragment code

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/userClickButton"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:text="Click on Me"
/>
```

Java code in the Fragment

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_view, null);
    Button userClickButton = (Button)root.findViewById(R.id.userClickButton);
    userClickButton.setOnClickListener(new View.onClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // Something to do
        }
    });
}
```

Advantages:

- Each fragment will have its own code

Disadvantage:

- Each fragment must have its own onClickListener
- The communication between the fragment must require the Activity to implement an Interface.

Which one do you think is better?
(Please provide your answer with arguments)

Answer (score 1):

Your `OnClickListener` should be in the Fragment that the View is in.  Fragments are supposed to be basically autonomous units.  The role of the Activity is to simply facilitate communication between the Fragments.

For example, if you later decided that your Fragment needs to be hosted in another Activity, then you would need to re-implement all your code that you had in the prior Activity.  Whereas if you treated the Fragment as autonomous, you could easily host it in as many Activities as you want.

I think the important design question for you is why your Activity even needs to know about the Button in the Fragment being clicked.  This is normally not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

It depends.

Sometimes it's better to use "OnClick" attribute in XML and implement it in the Activty.

Other times it's better to implement a java listener in the fragment. It depends on button action.

If this button action only affects to fragment's view (example: show or hide another fragment's view or something like that), it's better to use java listener, but if this button affects main activity's process (example: perform login, go to next activity...etc...), it's better to implement OnClick attribute in XML.

Android's doc doesn't prefer one or other...
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html